# google analytics for blog page views using google tag mananger

Tags: google-analytics

I want to track the pageviews of my blogs in google analytics. I have created a tag and created variable with UA string - tracking ID and tried to trigger on regex

```
/https:\/\/([^"\/]*\/)*blog\/([^"]*)/
```

containing blog but the count dosen't increase in google analytics.

Comment: As a side note: keep in mind that most data is not updated in analytics in real-time. Sometimes it takes up to 24 hours to see changes. P.S: Maybe posting how you init the analytics script (without ids of course) can aid in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Page Path` variable and set trigger like that:

`Page Path` - `matches RegEx (ignore case)` - `^/blog/.*`